# Can't resolve all parameters for PostsComponent

Tags: angular

I want to recover the API data but it gives me the error.

> Can't resolve all parameters for PostsComponent

**posts.component.ts**

```js
    import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/Http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'posts',
      templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
    })
    export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private http : Http) { 
         this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response=>
          { console.log(response)
         })
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/Http';
    import { EmailService } from './email.service';
    import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
    import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
    import { ResumePipe } from './resume.pipe';
    import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
    import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
    import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
    import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
    import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';
    import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CourseComponent,
        CoursesComponent,
        ResumePipe,
        FavoriteComponent,
        PanelComponent,
        InputFormatDirective,
        ContactFormComponent,
        SignupFormComponent,
        PostsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule

      ],
      providers: [CoursesService,EmailService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are importing wrong `Http`, instead you should use `HttpClient`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { 
     this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response=>
      { console.log(response)
     })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

if you want to import `HttpClient` from selenium too you can do it so

```
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient as Http } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http : Http) { 
     this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response=>
      { console.log(response)
     })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Also you should import `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpModule` in your `app.module.ts`.

And one thing too, don't do your Http calls in your constructor, it's a side effect for constructor and can lead to unexpected issues, instead move it in service, inject it in the component and call method from the service inside `ngOnInit` life cycle hook